# shell "if" statement

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, mv

I am new to unix and am practicing a simple script to unzip a load of files within a specified directory.  I need the program to move the zipped file into another folder when it is done unzipping it (I called this oldzipped folder).  For simplicity, I have removed the part of the code unzipping the file and currently have the program working for a specific file rather than the *tar.7z file extention.  For some reason, the mv statement is not working.  Unix is saying the following when I try to run the script.  Could someone give me a hand with this?  Again, I know this is the long way of doing things, but I want practice writing a script.  Please be nice, as I am very new to Unix :(

unzip5: line 14: [ASDE0002.tar.7z]: command not found

```
#!~/bin/bash
# My program to try to unzip several files with ending of tar.7z
# I have inserted the ability to enter the directory where you want this to be done

echo "What file location is required for unzipping?"

read dirloc

cd $dirloc
mkdir oldzippedfiles
for directory in $dirloc
        do
                if
                [ASDE0002.tar.7z]
                then
                mv -f ASDE0002.tar.7z $dirloc/oldzippedfiles
        fi
        done

echo "unzipping of file is complete"

exit 0
```

Comment: You probably mean `[ -e ASDE0002.tar.7z ]`. (Hint `man test` can give you the options for `test`, which IIRC is embedded in bash as `[ ]`). Also the beginning of the script looks a bit weird `#!~/bin/bash`, unless you have manually installed `bash` in `~/bin/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` is the name of a (sometimes built-in) command which accepts arguments. As such you need to put a space after it as you would when invoking any other program. Also, you need a test. For example, to determine if the file exists and is a file, you need to use `-f`:

```
if [ -f ASDE0002.tar.7z ]
then
    mv -f ASDE0002.tar.7z $dirloc/oldzippedfiles
fi
```

Here are some [other possible tests](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test).

Comment: I commonly use `[ -r somefile ]` to make sure that I can read the file. (`-r` is the check for file is readable)